# Escape colon character in Solr wildcard query

Tags: solr, lucene

I'm trying to query a text_general field named body for times like 9:15, 9:15pm, 9:15p, etc. I tried both of the following queries via the REST API without success:

- `q=body:9\:15*` gives me no hits, missing docs that mention 9:15
- `q=body:"9:15"*` gives me all docs, including docs that have nothing resembling 9:15

Debugging in Chrome, I enter these directly in the browser. I've also tried encodeURIComponent on the values to make sure the content isn't lost in HTTP translation. Same outcome either way.

I'm guessing there's a simple answer here and my mental model of how Solr queries work is just broken.

Answer (score 1):

In cases like that I often do 2 things:

1. Turn Solr query debug on, so I can see that really goes into query. You will see extra node at the end of response.

   ```
   &debug=query
   ```
2. Examine field analyser with Analysis tool. (url based on Solr's example core)

   ```
   http://localhost:8983/solr/#/collection1/analysis?analysis.fieldvalue=9%3A30pm&analysis.query=9%3A30&analysis.fieldtype=text_general&verbose_output=0
   ```

Both methods should tell you exactly what is going wrong with your query. In second one you can check how matching work without reindexing anything.

Answer (score 1):

Your time string gets tokenized following the [Unicode standard annex UAX#29](http://unicode.org/reports/tr29/#Word_Boundaries).
So the colon should be stripped out.
I think if you check you will see that your results should contain either 9 or 15.